# How to add dynamically-created sub-forms as a collection in Symfony/Silex FormBuilder?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, silex, formbuilder

I'm trying to dynamically generate a form based on user-provided field definitions. This is fairly straightforward for the basic form:

```
$builder = $app['form.factory']->createBuilder('form', $my_data);
foreach ($my_user_provided_field_definitions as $field) {
    $builder->add($field->handle, $field->type, $field->options);
}
$form = $builder->getForm();
```

But I also want to have sub-forms using the `collection` field type, and while it is so easy to dynamically generate the top-level form as I've done above, it does not seem possible to dynamically generate a sub-form for the `collection` field because all of the docs and sample code I've come across utilize either a single field like so:

```
$builder->add('my field', 'collection', array(
    'type' => 'text',
    'allow_add' => true,
));
```

...or a custom "Type" object, like so:

```
$builer->add('my field', 'collection', array(
    'type' => new TagType(),
    'allow_add' => true,
));
```

The `TagType` class in the above example must be defined in code (see http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/form/form_collections.html )... but my problem is that I cannot have the class defined in code because these sub-forms are dynamically generated based on user data -- so I do not know what fields the sub-form will contain until run-time!

Is there a way to dynamically generate the sub-forms that can then be passed in to the top-level form, or is this a use case that is not handled by the Symfony FormBuilder?

Comment: Have you looked at: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html?  It lets you add types based on user data.  Let me know if this does not solve your problem.  I can dynamically generate forms based on a yaml file.  It's not exactly what you are asking for but it should be close.  But it is a bit involved.

Comment: No, I had not seen that (thanks for the link). It is indeed a bit involved. My quick read on that is I still need to create a class for the "FormType", but inside that class I can dynamically add fields. It can be tough to "translate" the Symfony code samples to Silex, but I'll give it a shot. Thanks!